# How does peer2peer work through a router?

Tags: p2p, nat-traversal

How does one PC connect to another over the internet to another PC?

An example would be a program listening for connections on PC 1. PC 1 sits behind Router 1. PC 2 has a client program trying to connect to PC 1.

What is the correct technology/technique to use as the listening program in this situation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [article by Brian Ford](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/) explains how peer to peer communication across NATs work.

Most routers also expose a [Universal Plug and Play interface (uPnP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) which can be used for port forwarding and NAT traversal.

You should also check out the [STUNT library](http://nutss.gforge.cis.cornell.edu/stunt.php) which is an easy to use NAT traversal library.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on [NAT Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal). NAT traversal is a general term for techniques that establish and maintain TCP/IP network connections traversing network address translation (NAT) gateways.