# C# How to send string via UDP without Port Forwarding?

Tags: c#, udp

I need something simillar to this:

---

```
var client = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("23.114.44.195"), 11000);
client.Connect(ep);

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");
client.Send(data, data.Length);
```

---

The listener runs on that IP at PORT: 11000, but i don't want to port forward in my router (because I want to publish this app).

So, here is the question: How to send string via UDP without Port Forwarding?

Comment: As far as I know that can't be done without a server in the middle that both clients would connect to and at the very least, rely the messages from one to the other.

Comment: So if I want to send something withouth a server to an IP with a router, I have to port forward?

Comment: only port forwarding or udp hole punching or stun server

Comment: Have a look the resources in the answer to this question, it will explain far better than I could. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575448/how-does-peer2peer-work-through-a-router

Comment: Thanks in advance, i'll read it. How about UDP Hole Punching? What is this and how it works?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is.  You are not using broadcast, nor Multicast.  Your port number is 11000 which normally isn't blocked.  So your UDP should be the same as a TCP connection (without ACK/NACK).  So why do you need port forwarding?  Router should not be blocking standard UDP messages.

Comment: I don't know why, but I don't receive the string, also I port forwarded and I received it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NAT hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching), which doesn't require manual port forwarding configuration. It's quite simple technique. Please note that remote endpoint (receiver) should implement it too, not just sender.

In the simplest case, it works as:

```
[sender] <-> |internet| <-> [remote router with NAT] <-> [receiver]
```

Please note `sender` is not behind NAT.

To punch a hole from `senderIP:portX` to `receiverIP:portY`:
`sender` binds to `portX` and waits for communication initialisation from `receiver`. `receiver` binds to `portY` and sends a dummy packet to `senderIP:portX`. `sender` gets `receiverIP` (which is actually its router IP) and `portY` from the package and now sends meaningful data to this address. NAT remembered that communication with `senderIP:portX` was going from `receiver`s local IP and `portY`, so all data coming from `senderIP:portX` to the router's `portY` will be redirected to `receiver`s local IP.

For the case when both `sender` and `receiver` are behind NATs, you need a rendezvous server, for details check the link.

Comment: Ok, telling this to me it's easy, but either you do or not, I still don't know how to implement it *sad*. Any piece of code that could help me?

Comment: what exactly don't you understand? You can easily google a couple of C# implementations, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140450/udp-hole-punching-implementation, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12229756/453271

Comment: Thanks for your help, altough I found another way. C# programmatically port forwarding.